# What does "coefficients from all of $\mathbf{F} _q$" mean

Tags: ring-theory, terminology

I was reading [Wikipedia's page on Ring Learning with Errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_Learning_with_Errors), and came to wonder what is meant by "with coefficients from all of $\mathbf{F} _q$" which is a requirement for the set of known polynomials.

Does it just meant that they are not all small/large (compared to $q$), or is there a precise definition?

Comment: $\mathbb F_q$ denotes a [finite field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) of size $q$. If $q$ is a prime number, then $\mathbb F_q$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z / q \mathbb Z$ ("integers modulo $q$")

Comment: I knew that even before I started reading that wikipedia page, it's just the "coefficients from all of" bit I'm asking about.

Answer (score 1):

In the Ring Learning with errors context, some of the polynomials generated will have coefficients generated from a very small subset of Fq.  Such polynomials are considered "small" with respect to the infinity norm (the largest coefficient of the polynomial when the coefficients are viewed as integers in Z).  So when the writer states, "all of Fq" they are distinguishing that case from the restricted coefficient case.